# Multiplying an infinite sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a "challenge" problem in the current text I'm studying.

When simplified, the product,

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right),$$ becomes which of the following?

I spent quite a bit of time on the problem a few weeks ago and could never get my answer to match any of the answers given.

Comment: Hint: Try a small case, and rewrite terms in the product as simplified fractions. For example, $(1-1/3)(1-1/4) = (2/3)(3/4) = 2/4$. Now see if you can set up a general product which telescopes.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE:  Didn't see AWertheim's comment when I posted this.  Not trying to steal answers >.<

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=$$$$\left(\frac{2}{\color{blue}{3}}\right)\left(\frac{\color{blue}{3}}{\color{red}{4}}\right)\left(\frac{\color{red}{4}}{\color{green}{5}}\right)\left(\frac{\color{green}{5}}{\color{purple}{6}}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{\color{orange}{n-1}}{n}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I see it now.I couldn't figure out why he had a sequence problem in a text that doesn't cover sequences. But it was right before my eyes.

Comment: Certainly not that you need my permission at all, but no worries friend! Glad someone posted it as a cogent answer, and nice use of color. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the same thing as writing:
$$(\frac{2}{3})(\frac{3}{4})(\frac{4}{5})...(\frac{n-1}{n})$$
Which can be written as:
$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}\right)}{(\frac{1!}{2!})}$$
$$= \lim_{n \to\infty}\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{n!} \frac{2!}{1!}\right) = \lim_{n \to\infty}\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{n*(n-1)!} \frac{2}{1}\right) = \lim_{n \to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) \to \frac{2}{\infty} \to 0$$
Another way to think about it is that when you multiply it out, every number gets canceled out except a $2$ in the numerator, and $n$ in the denominator (see [Arthur's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/809386/10245)). Since $n$ approaches infinity, $\frac{2}{n}$ gets infinitely close to $0$. So we say that the *limit* as $n$ approaches infinity, of the sequence is equal to  $0$.

Comment: This answer is incredibly wrong in the first expression, but somehow corrects itself at the end!

Comment: The first expression should come out to $2/\sqrt \pi$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29! (but the last ! is part of the web page URL, so clicking on the link won't get the correct answer).

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F2)%21

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith - Maybe I misunderstood something about how factorials work, I assumed that $(\frac{1}{2})! = \frac{1!}{2!}$

Comment: But then by your logic you would have $(xy)! = x! y!$.  And simple counterexamples show this is false.  So yes, you do misunderstand factorials.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith - Fair enough. I edited the answer to reflect correct usage of factorials.